# Jquery to check whether div contains links from another div

Tags: jquery, element

I have two columns, Master and Slave, and I want to check which links in Master are not in Slave,and highlight them.

This, however, doesn't seem to be working:

```
$(".column2 a").each(function(){


    if ($('.column1').find($(this).html()).length == 0) {
     alert($(this).html()); 
     $(this).addClass('masterhilite');
    }

});
```

Any idea why this won't work? Thanks

Comment: Can you add html to this question?

Comment: Hm, you are putting an HTML string (returned by `.html()`) in a place where you should put a selector. I suggest you read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if a link with the same href attribute exists in `.column1`, if not highlight ?

```
$(".column2 a").filter(function(){
      return !$('.column1 a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').length;
}).addClass('masterhilite');
```

**EDIT:**

or to check for the same text:

```
$(".column2 a").filter(function(){
      return !$('.column1 a:contains(' + $(this).text() + ')').length;
}).addClass('masterhilite');
```

Comment: thanks. What would I do if I wanted to check the text contained in the <a> element instead of the URL?

Comment: @Rob - added a solution for something like that as well?